# One-Way collision / One-Sided collider

Tags: particles, physics, collision

[image]I try to fill up my mesh with particles(molecular addon) falling from top. What I would need is an one-way collision to "trap" the objects inside the mesh and form the shape if something like this is possible? Or does anybody know another way to fill a shape from bottom to top by falling objects?
Thanks!